# Bootstrap dismissable success message not showing longer with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have an ajax form which gets data with PHP `post` method. Instead of using the alert function of Javascript, I called bootstrap success message. But problem it doesn't show longer last only for less than a second. How to show its length until the user manually closed it as it's dismissable.

Coding Part:

```js
function send_form() {
  $.ajax({
     url: "./admin-security.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: {
       ip: $("#ip").val()
     },
     success: function(response) {
          if(response==1) {
               $("#ajax-ip-success").show();
              location.href = "./admin-security.php";
          }
          else alert("Fail! DataBase Error");
      }
  });
 }
```

```html
<?php
//--AJAX PART CALLING
      if(isset($_POST['ip'])){
          if($IP = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ip', 
            FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)){
          $add_ip = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO block_ip(b_ip) 
            VALUES(?)");
          $add_ip->bind_param("s",$IP);
          $add_ip->execute();
          $add_ip->store_result();
          $add_ip->close();
         echo 1;
          }
          else {
                echo 0;
          }
       exit;
      }
?>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade in" style="display: none;" id="ajax-ip-success">
                  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                  <strong>Success!</strong> IP added successfully.
                  </div>
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="ip"> Enter IP:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" name="ip" class="form-control" id="ip" />
      </div></div>
     <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
       <button type="button" onClick="send_form()" class="btn btn-default" 
        >Submit</button>
           </div></div>
         </div>
```

Comment: thats the correct behavior? it mean that ur server side respond is fast, any issue? if you want to delay it, you can use `setTimeout()`, or don't call the redirect in success, but based on variable, when user click close, only redirect it

Comment: no issue from the server side. Its just the alert messages show up that fast, that user can not read what is written.

Comment: I updated my question with the php part

Comment: I tried `setTimeout($("#ajax-ip-success").show(),7000);` didn't worked.

Comment: setTimeout(function(){     location.href = "./admin-security.php"; },2000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Timeout for location redirect

```
setTimeout(function(){
 location.href = "./admin-security.php"; 
},2000);
```

Comment: Can we add click function here? so that if the user closes the dismissible alert it redirects?

Comment: ya.set timeout only wait for specific time which is mentioned as 2000